# ResourceDictionary fails to merge external ResourceDictionaries

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I Have a ResourceDictionary Generic.xaml which consists of a set of other resource dictionaries, this is achieved by merging dicionaries. If no resources other than merged dictionaries are defined in my Generic.xaml, during the runtime no styles gets applied.
However if I define any styles in the Gerneric.xaml all starts to work properly.

So the example below doesn't work (this is from my Generic.xaml)

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/ResourceDictionaries/CommonControls/CommonControlsResources.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!--<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}"/>-->
```

And here is the working version:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/ResourceDictionaries/CommonControls/CommonControlsResources.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}"/>
```

Why is that happening?

**Edit:**

To pin point the problem I have created a sample solution. So the structure of the project is following:

**ProjectA** WPF Windows Application

**ProjectC** Class Library, containing styles which are share among all project in the solution folder.

Here is the ProjectA:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectC;component/Themes/ThemeZ.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <!--<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}"/>-->
</ResourceDictionary>


    <Application x:Class="MergedResourceDictionaryIssue.App"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
        <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Application.Resources>
    </Application>


    <Window x:Class="MergedResourceDictionaryIssue.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <Button/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Here is the ProjectC:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <!-- Styles for all our buttons, let make them all red squares -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="50"
                          Height="50"
                          Background="Red" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And again if I uncomment the code in the ResourceDictionary project renders as expected, but otherwise the resource dictionary is simply ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to me, a Dictionary can only contain : 
- merged dictionaries
- OR styles

**Edit :** They are discussing about it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f1231b5c-9fd2-40b7-8398-ebf7af8c0d2f/) It's a "known" issue and the trick that you used is the currently workaround.

Comment: You are probably misunderstanding my question. I have just updated my question, I hope it is now more clear what is the issue.

Comment: In effect... so sorry :/

Can you put a little piece of code where you call a style from CommonControlsResources.xaml ?

Have you already "minimized" your code ? For example just creating a simple style in CommonControlsResources.xaml, in a new WPFApplication, with just a control getting this simple style ?

Comment: @metalcam I have created a sample project to eliminate the details of my project. See the code above.

Comment: hum... I can't test right know but have you ever tried to do the same thing in 1 project without `pack://application:.....` ?

Comment: My question is NOT how to overcome that issue, I have found a way to overcome it myself. The question is WHY this issue is happening!? I need to have a ResourceDictionary in a separate project.

Comment: I understand, but indeed finding out what is EXACTLY not working can allow to find an answer !

Anyway, I tried your architecture, and it works perfectly...

I have a C# Class Library in which I added PresentationCore, Presentation Framework and WindowsBase, with a "Themes\ThemeZ.xaml" and a WPF Application With A button in my window, a "Themes\Generic.xaml" where ResourceDictionary Source is exactly what you put here... (and the uncomment style is still uncomment).
Are you using MVVM Light ? as I see MainWindow, I'm just wondering...

Comment: What do you mean by without pack://application:....? Do you mean referencing a ResourceDictionary from the same project? Why you are deducing from the MainWindow that I am using MVVM light? In fact in my real application I am using PRISM, but in the example above it is a simple WPF.

Comment: What do you get when your run that code? As I am able to reproduce that issue on Windows XP, and windows 7 (.NET 4)..

Comment: I get a red square in a window :)
Notice that I used visual studio 2008 (WPF 3.5), with a simple wpf application (with not any MVVM pattern) !

Comment: Do you get a red square with uncommented style for tooltip?

Comment: yes ! Just try it with a simple WPF app, without prim or any other pattern template !

If you want I can send you the project I created if you don't believe me ;-)

Comment: The project I am using to reproduce an issue does not contain any design pattern.. But I have change the Framework to 3.5 and indeed it starts to work, that is weird.

Comment: Your problem is a known issue !!
[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f1231b5c-9fd2-40b7-8398-ebf7af8c0d2f/) is the same issue.

Unfortunately I think you already find out the "best" answer adding a style =_=... Read all this thread, you will maybe find another solution !

Comment: Unfortunately it is still a workaround, but we can't do anything with bugs in WPF :/ Hope it gets fixed soon.